# 1.9 - Custom category list template

Tags: magento-1.9

I want a custom category list template for just 1 category.

In the layout update I've added:

```
<reference name="category.products">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>catalog/category/custom_view_list.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

This replaces the `category/view` template but I actually want to replace the `catalog/product/list` template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This replaces the category/view template but I actually want to replace the catalog/product/list template

Try this then

```
<reference name="product_list">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>catalog/category/custom_view_list.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that just for **One Category**, you can't do it in **xml file** but in **Admin config layout** part in `Admin >Catalog> category manager>`select your category and in `custom design>` you put your custom xml in `custom updates design` part

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>catalog/category/custom_view_list.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```